# No output from regex extracting data from Ping statistics. How to fix it?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, ping

I have the following string which is what I have received at the end of a ping result, I wish to extract the min,avg,max and mdev using regex in java

```
[1463895327]PING www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24) 100(128) bytes of data.
[1463895327]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=868 ms
[1463895328]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=892 ms
[1463895329]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=814 ms
[1463895330]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=4 ttl=110 time=1009 ms
[1463895331]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=5 ttl=110 time=1006 ms
[1463895332]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=6 ttl=110 time=984 ms
[1463895333]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=7 ttl=110 time=1004 ms
[1463895334]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=8 ttl=110 time=1006 ms
[1463895335]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=9 ttl=110 time=1013 ms
[1463895336]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=10 ttl=110 time=578 ms
[1463895336]
[1463895336]--- www.gov.bw ping statistics ---
[1463895336]10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9007ms
[1463895336]rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms, pipe 2
```

I want to extract the values from the substring

```
min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms
```

What would be the regex expression which would allow me to extract these 4 values an array of type double? The expected result is an array with

```
[274.175,430.739,818.328,147.779]
```

I've already tried the expression:

```
rtt\s+min\/avg\/max\/mdev\s+=\s+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s+ms
```

Using

```
// No error but all values null

public static String[] parsePingStatisticsMinAvgMaxMdev(String input) throws TimeNotFoundException {
    // Capture the rtt min/avg/max/mdev times
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("rtt\\s+min\\/avg\\/max\\/mdev\\s+=\\s+([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\/([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)\\s+ms");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()){
        int i = 0;
        String[] s = new  String[4];
        while(m.find()){
            s[i] = m.group(++i);
        }
        return s;
    }
    else
        throw new TimeNotFoundException();

}
```

I get no output (below). How do I fix this?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java" ...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Shouldn't the expected result be an array with `578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095`?.I don't see `274.175..` anywhere.

Comment: On a side note: you can also do `\\d+` to represent digits in regexp. Example: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("min\\/avg\\/max\\/mdev\\s+=\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+ms");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

```
public class Main {

    static String s = "[1463895327]PING www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24) 100(128) bytes of data.\n" +
            "[1463895327]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=868 ms\n" +
            "[1463895328]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=2 ttl=110 time=892 ms\n" +
            "[1463895329]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=3 ttl=110 time=814 ms\n" +
            "[1463895330]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=4 ttl=110 time=1009 ms\n" +
            "[1463895331]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=5 ttl=110 time=1006 ms\n" +
            "[1463895332]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=6 ttl=110 time=984 ms\n" +
            "[1463895333]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=7 ttl=110 time=1004 ms\n" +
            "[1463895334]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=8 ttl=110 time=1006 ms\n" +
            "[1463895335]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=9 ttl=110 time=1013 ms\n" +
            "[1463895336]108 bytes from www.gov.bw (168.167.134.24): icmp_seq=10 ttl=110 time=578 ms\n" +
            "[1463895336]\n" +
            "[1463895336]--- www.gov.bw ping statistics ---\n" +
            "[1463895336]10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9007ms\n" +
            "[1463895336]rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms, pipe 2";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(parsePingStatisticsMinAvgMaxMdev(s)));
    }

    public static String[] parsePingStatisticsMinAvgMaxMdev(String input) { throws TimeNotFoundException {
        // Capture the rtt min/avg/max/mdev times
        Pattern p = Pattern p = Pattern.compile("rtt\\s+min\\/avg\\/max\\/mdev\\s+=\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\/(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+ms");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        if (m.find()) {
            int i = 1;
            String[] s = new String[4];
            while (m.find(i) && i <= 4) {
                s[i - 1] = m.group(i);
                i++;
            }
            return s;
        } else
            throw new TimeNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Output:

> [578.263, 917.875, 1013.707, 132.095]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a dream

Comment: Please close that question with marking answer as a right one.